# Let $A$, $B$ be two normed vector spaces and $T \in L(A,B)$. Prove $T$ is continous iff it is continous at zero.

Tags: real-analysis

Only if:

If $f$ is continuous, then we say: for each 
$p \in V, \forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0 s.t. \forall v\in V, ||v - p|| < \delta \implies ||f(v) - f(p)|| < \epsilon$.
Let $p = 0$. Then $T$ is continuous at zero.

If:

This is the part I am not sure about.

If $f$ continuous at zero, then $ \forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0 s.t. \forall v\in V, ||v - 0|| < \delta \implies ||f(v) - f(0)|| < \epsilon$.

Take any $p \in V$. Then $||v|| = ||v + p - p||$. Let $ \alpha = v + p $. Then we have $ || \alpha - p || < \delta \implies || f(\alpha) - f(p) || < \epsilon $. Since $ \alpha$ is arbitrary, this means $f$ is continuous at $p$. Since $p$ was arbitrary, conclude $f$ is continuous everywhere on $V$.

Comment: wait I wrote that too badly!

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is continuous in $0$, for every $y_n \to 0$

$f(y_n) \to 0$.

Pick one $x$:

for every $x_n \to x$,

$(x_n-x) \to 0$.

Thus $y_n = x_n-x$ is such that

$f(x_n) - f(x) = f(x_n-x) = f(y_n) \to 0 $.

Thus $f(x_n) \to f(x)$.